# need to make a simple Windows app, what languague should I use?

Tags: windows

I need to make s very simple app, with a canvas where the user would be able to drag & drop PNG files, drag, scale and rotate them on the canvas and export to XML their name & coordinates.

I'm pretty good at Android(java) programming, but as I just tried plain java with windowsBuilder for the first time, it appeared to be rather inconvenient and probably would take at least a few days to find my way around in it.

So I thought, maybe you could suggest some simple "program maker" style language/ide that could be quickly picked up for such purpose?

Right now I'm thinking of Flash... any other ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You will always take some time and practice to find your way around. Everyone here has their favorite tools, but they may not fit your needs best. I'd say stick with Java if it's what you know already and simply learn the new tools in addition to the known language.

Comment: Wow, do you really think a couple of days is too much investment of your time to learn programming on an unfamiliar platform?  Try Logo

Comment: >>> couple of days is too much investment of your time to learn programming on an unfamiliar platform
Well yes, right now I just need to make that app as fast as possible, rather then invest time into learning new stuff... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with C#, with the .NET framework.

As you already know Java, it shouldn't be that hard, as C# is also an object-oriented language.

They are some differences, of course, and I won't explain them here.
But if you want a real Windows app, it may be your best choice, as you'll then have access to all the Windows features through the .NET framework.
Everything is very well documented.

You can also choose C++ (managed), but it might be a little harder, coming from Java.

About the IDE, simply use VisualStudio (the express edition is free).

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Actually I do know C#, only forgot it partly, had worked in it a lot a few years ago. :) Yet for the current case I guess it could be a bit of an overkill. :) I'll try Flash, if nothing better comes up, and if it won't work, then will turn to c#.

Comment: Good luck with Flash then : )

Comment: Looked more into Flash and yes, it seems different from java and sharp... so installing visual studio for now. :)

Answer (score 1):

I learned JavaScript (I know it's not Java, but similar nonetheless and still object oriented) first and then C++. The transition was quite easy since both are more-or-less object oriented. Like Macmade said, Visual Studio is great to begin, but I prefer using gedit and then compiling with G++. It's more forgiving than Visual Studio and you don't have to create a project and whatnot just to start writing the code. With a text editor like gedit and a standalone compiler, G++, it's much easier to just write the code and then build the program.

I'd stay away from Flash. I know AS2/3 pretty well and I can say that C is much easier to code, at least for me. Everyone has their personal preferences, though. One plus to C is you don't have to buy Flash.